# Advaita on other acharyas?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, reference-request

Do advaita believe that ramanujacharya is avatar of Adi sesha
And madhavcharya is avatar of vayu
And Krishna chaitanya is avatar of Krishna

Any reference that Adi shankara charya obey that dvaita , vishiadvaita is real

(Note : I do not want answer for swami Vivekananda )

Comment: Adi Shankaracharya came before Ramanujacharya and Madhvacharya, so how would he comment on whether they are incarnations of Adisesha and Krishna? He didn't comment because he lived before their time.

Comment: I want answer from Swami vidyaranya and other jagatgurus of other peetas